# EA mobile games site question?

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

2 question on this site:

http://iphone.eamobile.com/home

- They hide the URL input bar somehow – is this CSS?
- The bottom tray (a la jQTouch) - is that JS or CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They hide the URL input bar somehow

this:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

[docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html). There are security concerns with this (as well as usability): sites can replace the location bar with a spoofed one that pretends to be a different site.

> The bottom tray - is that JS or CSS?

It's plain CSS `position: fixed; bottom: 0`.